# How should I set an interpreter in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

First of all, there are two Python files in the directory in total. and I tried to run those two, but it kept showing only one result of the file named "hello.py". If I want to see the result of the other, I have to change the"script path" to the file's name. How do I resolve this problem? I want to see all the results without changing the script path one by one. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Youi right click anywhere in the editor and choose *"Run file..."*

Comment: Or add a new configuration and just change between them instead of changing the path on a single shared configuration. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html#create-permanent

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by:

1. Opening the file
2. Right clicking
3. Pressing run file

So, you can run them all individually like that and then scroll through the terminal to see all of the outputs.

Comment: It was just that simple Thank you so much!

Comment: @daehee_c It would be great if you could upvote and accept since this helped you! :)